# Accessing a Database from a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, attr-accessor

I'm writing a Rails application and I created a Grocery model that references a database table of grocery items. The Grocery table has just one column named "item".

The Grocery model has a LIST constant that contains a bunch of "item"s. I seed the database with these items initially with the seeds.rb file. I also created a rake task to add/remove groceries from the database. The database is successfully populated.

The problem: I want to check the Grocery table within the Grocery model and other models to see whether or not a certain item is in the database. Every time I do a pry and access the Grocery table from within the Grocery model, I can't see any db items. (However, I can see the db items when I do a Grocery.all from the console and in rake tasks.)

I've added attr_accessor :item to the Grocery model. This still does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what you are doing and how you are doing it. In the console, what is the output of Grocery.count and Grocery.all.pluck(:item)?

Comment: Is your table called `groceries`? Also, it would be helpful if you showed the code for your `Grocery` model.

Comment: in the console: output of Grocery.count is 13 -- the amount of groceries. output of Grocery.all is all the groceries. prying into Grocery model: output of Grocery.count is 0 -- the amount of groceries. output of Grocery.all is an empty array. @BrentEicher

Comment: table is called groceries - model is called Grocery @JakeShorty

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question? And please paste what you tried in the pry console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not added any default scope to the Grocery model, you should be able to fetch all the groceries inside Grocery or other models by using `Grocery.all`.
If you want to find if a certain grocery item exists in the grocery table, you can use `Grocery.exists?(grocery_item_id)`.
I hope it helps, if it doesn't, would recommend you to paste your model code here in the question.